# Why does database initialization fail with "ERROR: improper qualified name (too many dotted names)"?

Tags: postgresql, scala, slick

I'm using Scala 2.10 and [Slick](http://slick.typesafe.com/) 2.10-1.0.1 with plain queries.

I tried to init a lazy evaluating database with Tomcat at `localhost`. For query evaluation I use PostgreSQL on port `5432`.

As I tried to compile I got following error message:

```
ERROR org.quartz.core.JobRunShell - Job DEFAULT.MissionLifecycleManager threw an unhandled Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: improper qualified name (too many dotted names)
  Position: 16
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2102) ~[postgresql-9.1-901.jdbc4.jar:na]
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1835) ~[postgresql-9.1-901.jdbc4.jar:na]
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:257) ~[postgresql-9.1-901.jdbc4.jar:na]
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:500) ~[postgresql-9.1-901.jdbc4.jar:na]
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:388) ~[postgresql-9.1-901.jdbc4.jar:na]
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:381) ~[postgresql-9.1-901.jdbc4.jar:na]
at scala.slick.jdbc.StatementInvoker.results(StatementInvoker.scala:34) ~[slick_2.10-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]
at scala.slick.jdbc.StatementInvoker.elementsTo(StatementInvoker.scala:17) ~[slick_2.10-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]
....
```

This is the code of my initialisation:

```scala
import com.weiglewilczek.slf4s.Logging
import scala.slick.driver.PostgresDriver._
import scala.slick.session.Database
import Database.threadLocalSession
import scala.slick.jdbc.{GetResult, StaticQuery => Q}
import scala.slick.driver.PostgresDriver.simple._

object SQLUtilities extends Logging with ServiceInjector {
    lazy val db = init()

    private def init() = {
        info("Connecting to postgres database at localhost") //writes in a log file

        val qe = Database.forURL("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432", "user", "pass", driver = "org.postgresql.Driver")
        info("Connected to database")
        qe
    }
}
```

Obviously, something went wrong. So I think, my database initiallisation is not correct. Do I have forgotten some parameters? Are my parameters correct at all?

An another - not so fatal - question: If I have a body where I want to log something at the beginning and at the end of a method - let's say always the same log message, but different bodys - as a sign that I started and leaved this method... Is there a proper way to do this than this example here in `init()`?

Answer (score 3):

Specify a database in your connection string "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/somedatabase".

See http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html

Comment: shouldn't it be `...localhost:5432/somedatabase` instead of `:`

Comment: Is there a difference using `org.postgresql.Driver` or `scala.slick.driver.PostgresDriver`? Would Scala differ here?

Comment: The former is the jdbc-driver. The latter is the Slick-driver which can work with different jdbc-drivers. Not sure there exist multiple implementations in the case of postgres, but with other dbs that is the case.